# How to change yii2 default module

Tags: module, yii2

Hello I am not an expert in Yii2 and would appreciate any help, We want to change our default module,
Our logic:

site implements a use of wildcard domain, https://example.com,
    we implement a bootstrap component to Identify a use of a "subdomain" in the 
    url I.E. https://sub.example.com,

```
$config = [
'id' => 'basic',
'name' => 'exapmle',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => [
    'log',
    'devlogin',
    'app\components\SubBootstrap', #this is the bootstrap component we use
    'app\components\ThemeBootstrap',
],...
```

now we would have liked to use the same logic to change the default module to a new "submodule" but we can't use the bootstrap because it happens after the default module has been applied.

obviously we can have an explicit url call for the module I.E.

```
'modules' => [
    'sub'=>[
        'class' => 'app\modules\sub\Module',
    ],...
```

but that means that the url would look like https://somesub.example.com/sub/ which is undesirable.

thank you very much

Comment: does the name of the module depend on the subdomain or do you want / on every subdomain to call the same module?

Comment: Depends on what you want, you might either set https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-application#$defaultRoute-detail to 'sub/default/index' or configure pretty URLs: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#using-pretty-urls

Comment: @cebe we want the same module every time. in addition it's not only nice url it's also best practice to keep logic of sub separated from the rest of the code base. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, what you can do is override the `UrlManager` component and manually adjust the path to reflect the module that you want to envoke behind the scenes.

So your code would look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace app\components;

use Yii;

class UrlManager extends \yii\web\UrlManager
{
    public function parseRequest($request)
    {
        if (!empty(Yii::$app->sub)) {
            $pathInfo = $request->pathInfo;
            $moduleIds = array_keys(Yii::$app->modules);
            $inModule = false;
            foreach ($moduleIds as $moduleId) {
                if (preg_match("/^{$moduleId}/", $pathInfo)) {
                    $inModule = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!$inModule) {
                $pathInfo = 'sub/' . $pathInfo;
                $request->setPathInfo($pathInfo);
            }
        }

        return parent::parseRequest($request);
    }
}
```

and then in config/web.php:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'app\components\UrlManager',
    ...
],
```

Comment: Thanks @Chaim really worked like a charm exactly that way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the module configuration. You need to change web-server path to this module and architech the UrlManager rules; 
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing

Bootstraping yii module it's only some way to load it before another components.
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-bootstrapping